# Laravel database err

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I am using laravel insert syntax

```
DB::table($tableName)->insert(
                array(  
                    'COLL_COD' => $row_data[0],
                    'CATE' => $row_data[1],
                    'INP_YR' => $row_data[2],
                    'ROLL_NO' => $row_data[3],
                    'COLL_NAME' => "'$row_data[4]'",
                    'ROLL' => $row_data[5],
                    'NUMBER' => $row_data[6],
                    'NAME' => "'$row_data[7]'",
                    'SEX' => "'$row_data[8]'",
                    'REG_ALF' => "'$row_data[9]'",
                    'REG_NO' => $row_data[10],
                    'REG_YR' => $row_data[11],
                    'SUB' => "'$row_data[12]'",
                    'PAPER' => "'$row_data[13]'",
                    'OPT' => "'$row_data[14]'",
                    'DETAIL' => "'$row_data[15]'",
                    'A_B' => "'$row_data[16]'",
                    'H_P' => "'$row_data[17]'",
                    'TH_PR' => "'$row_data[18]'",
                    'FULL_MK' => $row_data[19],
                    'MK_OBT' => "'$row_data[20]'",
                    'TAG' => $row_data[21],
                    'PAP' => "'$row_data[22]'"
                      )
            );
```

getting error below

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'SEX' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `2023-2024_3_appearingstudents` (`COLL_COD`, `CATE`, `INP_YR`, `ROLL_NO`, `COLL_NAME`, `ROLL`, `NUMBER`, `NAME`, `SEX`, `REG_ALF`, `REG_NO`, `REG_YR`, `SUB`, `PAPER`, `OPT`, `DETAIL`, `A_B`, `H_P`, `TH_PR`, `FULL_MK`, `MK_OBT`, `TAG`, `PAP`) values (108, 1234, 21, 1001, 'EGRA SARADA SASHI BHUSAN COLLEGE, EGRA', 1234108, 211001, 'ASARUL MALLICK', 'M', 'VU21', 1008879, 2022, 'COAGCC', '7', '', 'Corporate Accounting', 'A', 'GCC', 'TH', 60, '', 4, ''))

but I have copied the sql from here and ran in phpmyadmin it is getting inserted.

I have tried to increase field size of 'SEX' column. It is showing the same error.

Comment: Do you really want to insert `'M'`  instead of `M` in that column?